# How to Calculate the Mass of an Isothermal Atmosphere

Tags: atmospheric-science

A homework question asks us to assume that the Earth's atmosphere is isothermal, and calculate the mass of the atmosphere. It gives no other suggestion as to how we might approach this computation.
Additionally, the only information in the chapter that might be useful is the derivation for the scale height of the Earth's atmosphere.
I imagine that the solution will involve integrating along the height of the atmosphere to account for the variable pressure, otherwise I am lost. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

here is the easy way to solve this problem, which requires neither the isothermality assumption nor knowledge of the total height of the air column. at the earth's surface, each square inch of area experiences a force due to the weight of the air above it of 14.7 pounds. The surface area of the earth is 7.906 x 10^17 square inches. Multiplying this by 14.7 pounds per square inch yields 1.162 x 10^19 pounds. this is equal to 5.264 x 10^18 kilograms for the total mass of the earth's atmosphere. 
for comparison, the wikipedia value is given as 5.15 x 10^18 kilograms.

Answer (score 0):

For an isothermal sphere the density profile is

$$
\rho = \frac{\sigma^2}{2\pi G r} \tag{1}
$$

so that the mass is

$$
M_{12} = \int_{r_1}^{r_2}{\rm d}r~r^2\rho(r) \tag{2}
$$

The constant $\sigma^2$ can be estimated through the temperature

$$
m\sigma^2 \sim k_bT
$$

Comment: Are the limits of integration the height of the atmosphere, from the ground to the top? If so how do I know what height to use, given that the atmosphere thins gradually rather than stopping suddenly.

Comment: You could explain the reasoning behind all this...

Comment: @Rafael The limits are indeed the height of the atmosphere $r_1 = R_{\rm earth}$, $r_2 = R_{\rm atm}$, this last term is indeed a bit tricky to estimate since, as you mention, there's not a sharp edge.